# Unable to automatically step into the server. The debugger failed to stop in the server process

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

I receive the following error when attempting to Step Into a process using F11 in Visual Studio 2008 Team System:

**"Unable to automatically step into the server. The debugger failed to stop in the server process."**

I have searched pretty long and hard on the internet and the most relevant message I found was http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65004e38%28v=VS.90%29.aspx.  Unfortunately, this did not help.  All signs are pointing that my ASP.NET setup is incorrect, but it's the IIS environment that ships with VS2008 Team System so I didn't make any figuration changes.

The answer to this question, which sounds like it might have fixed my solution is no longer an active link: [Unable to automatically step into the server when debugging WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359288/unable-to-automatically-step-into-the-server-when-debugging-wcf).  Does anybody know how I can jump into and fix this problem?

Comment: I found the following article: 

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/40514aa7-58b2-4018-966a-da36834acb47

... but it didn't help since my development environment is also my server (using VS2008 Team System installation).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This took me 3 days and no less than 5 people looking at the problem to solve; although I'd like to report the exact problem I'm still left to speculate.  However, I am no longer getting this error when I do the following:

I opened the .cs file of the base class my service derived from within my Testing solution.  I set a break-point in the constructor of this base class.  Because the base class wasn't within the solution of either my web service nor my test solution (it was simply referenced), VS2008 was unable to break into this .cs file.

The solution was rather simple.  I opened the base class.cs file within my Testing solution (the file only, not the solution).  I set a break-point in the constructor class, and I was then able to step-into all other files from there.  Once I was able to successfully set a break-point and stop the debugger in the base class within my actual Test solution, I was able to continue debugging as I would normally expect.

My only conclusion to the root cause of this problem is that VS2008 is broken.  I'm sorry it's not much of an answer, but this is how I was able to resolve the issue which sunk over 30 hours of time.

Comment: My problem was that my configuration was wrong, and my service's initialization code was throwing an exception, in the base class from which my web service was derived. I figured this out when I tried to debug the webservice itself.

Comment: My setup wasn't the same a @Magnum's, but inspired by it I deleted all of my breakpoints, reset the two that I actually wanted and it works!

Answer (score 3):

This could be because the debug not reaching to your break point there may be some error occurring before it.Try add break point in the base class constructor.

Comment: Negative.  There was no error before the break point as described in my answer above... I was able to reach the break-point when I opened the base class and broke in the constructor.  The base class was in another solution altogether, and the assemblies were derived from that base class.  For whatever reason, VS2008 never broke into the derived function without setting a break point in the parent class first... I think what this did was force it to load the parent assemblies in the debug as well?  That's just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I encountered a similar issue and the problem was that I was in `Release` mode rather than `Debug` mode. Changing to `Debug` mode solved the problem. I'm using VS 2010.

Answer (score 1):

this problem can occur if you have another solution  opened and running (another instance of visual studio).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error once when I had the wrong project set as the startup project in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This same thing happened when I had the service open in a browser. I closed it out and it fixed the issue.

Guessing you have it open multiple times. (basically repeating what Avicena00 said)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to import a file that was too big. I had to increase the maxAllowedContentLength value in my requestLimits area in my web.config to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated this is an old problem, but I ran into it running later versions of Visual Studio, and have not seen the solution that I found listed. This problem in my experience happened when the service was using a lower version of .Net (in my case 3.0 vs 4.5). Changing the .Net version int he project properties to 4.5 (which matched the project referencing the service), solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: Tool > Options > Debugging > Use Managed Compatibility Mode

[Visual Studio 2018 Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhohH.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I had open the same project and its copy (in different directory) in two Visual Studio instances. Solution than in final was simple as closing all IIS instances of Web projects and closing all instances of Visual studio. After opening just one project at a time debugging started to work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when I debugged one and another solution. 
The answer is very simple 
Click on the solution->Properties->Multiple startup projects
Then select projects and click f11.